# Identify Eclipse Platform version in IBM RAD

Tags: eclipse, ide, ibm-rad

To find the Eclipse version we can go to `Help > about`.

What I don't understand is how I can identify the Eclipse version used in IBM-RAD. I can only see the RAD version via `Help > about` (I am using v7.5).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Via the Help menu, navigate to `About Rational® Application Developer for WebSphere® Software`

In that dialogue window, you should see a number of icons at the bottom. Select the one which looks closest to the Eclipse icon:

[image]
<sup>Icon from RAD 9.X</sup>

[image]
<sup>Icon from RAD 8.5.X</sup>

(You may hover over the icon -- the icon with alt-text "Eclipse.org" is the correct one).

In the new window you will see which Version your Eclipse Platform is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the details.I found it to be eclipse 3.4.2(Eclipse Ganymede SR)

Comment: @Yohannes Good, I'm glad this method works for RAD 7.5.X as well